# Transistor for DC motor and 9v

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, transistor

I have this schematic for a DC motor in my arduino, now I want to add 9v battery.

But I've seen that people use TIP120 transistor, I have BC548B, 
can I just put the 9v with that transistor?

[image]

Comment: What are the ratings of your motor, or do you have a datasheet for. otherwise, connect to 9V directly and measure the current draw and add give that info too.

Comment: The datasheet says 30 volt is the maximum.

Comment: @Gerben the transistor is max `100mA` this is surely not good for a motor?

Comment: That's the maximum. Just like you can put a 5w light bulb in the same socket as a 100w light bulb. The motor will use the amount of current it needs, even thought there might be more current available.

Comment: @Gerben and if the motor draws too much, poof, white smoke and fun :) The OP never stated a **motor type**. The OPs circuit is what they want to do(from what I can tell, with Vin as source), although if the motor ran on 5V it is possibly a low current then, but you could max the draw if the thing stalls or is under load. With a 5W you might not see much though.

Comment: If you use PWM, be sure to use a Transistor(preferably a MOSFET) that has max voltage 3times the supply voltage and a flyback diode.Also, measure the current drawn by the motor when connected directly to 9V supply.The max current rating of the transistor used should be approx 2 times the current drawn by the motor(in the prev test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many circuits using the [TIP120 NPN](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP120.pdf) transistor because it is a [darlington transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor). This is used because its max voltage is `60V` and the max current is `5A`, this means you can control a variety of external high current devices with low voltage circuitry because of the darlington arrangement.

You can use the [BC548B](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BC/BC547.pdf) with your motor(low current) and a 9V battery as it does handle `30V`, **but it is limited to `100mA`**, which is fine for tiny low current motors. But these are actually Amplifier transistors, so there main design area is not for inductive loads.

I recommend the TIP120 as this will ensure that you don't trash a transistor with current spikes as you could easily go over the 100mA spec of the BC548.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I see no external power supply in your schematic.
Secondly, you certainly CANNOT use a BC548 for controlling a motor.
MOSFETS are the best.

Comment: If you use PWM, be sure to use a Transistor(preferably a MOSFET) that has max voltage 3times the supply voltage and a flyback diode.Also, measure the current drawn by the motor when connected directly to 9V supply.The max current rating of the transistor used should be approx 2 times the current drawn by the motor(in the prev test).